# HTML5/CSS3: Three column site not filling viewport width

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm having difficulty getting my uneven three-column website to fill the entire width of the viewport. Ideally, the left column would cover 25% of the width, the middle 50%, and the right 25%. If I'm unable to achieve that, then I would ask for the "unit" of all three columns to itself be centered in the viewport. Right now, all three columns are squished to the left. Portability of the final solution is extremely important to me: both in terms of browsers, as well as in terms of devices, so I don't want to set much as fixed width/height.

[Screenshot of current problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYqqT.jpg)

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: #616161;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0d47a1;;
    height: 40px;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #5472d3;
    color: black;
}

main {
    background-color: #0d47a1;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.row {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}  

.column {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #373737;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:15px;
    float: left;
}

.left .right {
    width: 25%;
}

/* Middle column */
.middle {
    width: 50%;
}

.card {
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 25px;
}

article {
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

section {
  background-color: #616161;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #616161;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: #fcd734;
}

/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color:  #5472d3;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <h1>DASK: Divorced and Separated Koinonia</h1>
            <br text-decoration: italic>Turning the dusk of divorce into new dawn.</br>
        </header>
        <nav class="topnav">
        </nav>

        <main>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="column left">
                <section>
                    <article class="card">
                        <h4>Profile</h4>
                        <p>Coming soon</p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <h4>Forum Posts</h4>
                        <p>Coming soon</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section style="margin-top: 15px">
                    <h3>Events</h3>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </section>
            </section>
            
            <section class="column middle">
            <section>
                <h2>What is DASK?</h2>
                <p>
                    DASK, or Divorced and Separated Koinonia, is a retreat designed by and for
                    people who have experienced divorce and separation. It is founded in the
                    Catholic religious tradition, but all are welcome. DASK is based on the popular
                    Koinonia retreat.
                </p>
                <h2>What is Koinonia?</h2>
                <p>
                    Koinonia is retreat program that is popular nation-wide, but was first founded
                    in Springfield, IL for adults. The word "koinonia" itself comes from the Greek
                    word for "community". The Koinonia retreat is run by many parishes, dioceses,
                    and college campuses in order to form communities and friendships based in
                    Christ. DASK finds that the focus on community is helpful to people going
                    through divorce and/or separation; we find that it is easy to feel "alone"
                    going through this process.
                </p>
                <p>
                    The theme of every DASK weekend is the Paschal Mystery; that is, the life,
                    death, and resurrection of Jesus.
                </p>
                <h2>Where can I get more information?</h2>
                <li>Download our <a href="static/img/dask_brochure_2018.pdf">brochure</a>.</li>
                <li>Like our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/daskretreats">Facebook page</a>.</li>
                <li>Email us at <a href="mailto:daskretreatsk@gmail.com">daskretreats@gmail.com</a>.</li>
                <li>Follow us on Twitter <a href="https://www.twitter.com/daskretreats">@daskretreats</a>.</li>
                <h2>How do I sign up?</h2>
                <p>
                    <a href="static/img/dask_brochure_2018.pdf">Download our brochure</a>, complete
                    the registration form inside, and submit it via snail mail or
                    <a href="mailto:daskretreats@gmail.com">email</a>. We host two retreat weekends
                    a year: in the Spring at Columbia, IL, and in the Fall at Springfield, IL.
                </p>
            </section>
            </section>
            
            <section class="column right">
                <section>
                    <h4>Donate</h4>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </section>
                <section style="margin-top: 15px">
                    <article class="card">
                        <h4>Twitter</h4>
                        <p>Coming soon</p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <h4>News</h4>
                        <p>Coming soon</p>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
        </main>
        
        <footer>
        <p>
            Copyright (C) 2018: Divorced and Separated Koinonia, under the <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">CC BY-SA</a>.
            <br><a href="daskretreats@gmail.com.com">daskretreats@gmail.com</a>
        </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following code if you looking for it. I take few steps to achieve it. At first your selector was wrong like that `.left .right`, this is selecting right inside left it should `.left, .right`.

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
  }
        /* Added */
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  header {
    background-color: #616161;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  /* Style the top navigation bar */
  .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #0d47a1;;
   height: 40px;
  }
  
  /* Style the topnav links */
  .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /* Change color on hover */
  .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #5472d3;
   color: black;
  }
  
  main {
   background-color: #0d47a1;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
  
  .row {
   display: table;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
  }  
  
  .column {
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #373737;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
   border-radius: 25px;
   margin:15px;
   float: left;
  }
  
  .left, .right {
   width: calc(25% - 30px); // Deducted margin space 15+15 = 30px;
  }
  
  /* Middle column */
  .middle {
   width: calc(50% - 30px); // Deducted margin space 15+15 = 30px;
  }
  
  .card {
   height: 100px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
   border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  article {
    background-color: #8e8e8e;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
  section {
    background-color: #616161;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  footer {
   background-color: #616161;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
   border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  /* unvisited link */
  a:link {
    color: #fcd734;
  }
  
  /* visited link */
  
  a:visited {
    color:  #5472d3;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>DASK: Divorced and Separated Koinonia</h1>
        <br text-decoration: italic>Turning the dusk of divorce into new dawn.</br>
    </header>
    <nav class="topnav">
    </nav>
    
    <main>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="column left">
            <section>
                <article class="card">
                    <h4>Profile</h4>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </article>
                <article class="card">
                    <h4>Forum Posts</h4>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </article>
            </section>
            <section style="margin-top: 15px">
                <h3>Events</h3>
                <p>Coming soon</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        
        <section class="column middle">
        <section>
            <h2>What is DASK?</h2>
            <p>
                DASK, or Divorced and Separated Koinonia, is a retreat designed by and for
                people who have experienced divorce and separation. It is founded in the
                Catholic religious tradition, but all are welcome. DASK is based on the popular
                Koinonia retreat.
            </p>
            <h2>What is Koinonia?</h2>
            <p>
                Koinonia is retreat program that is popular nation-wide, but was first founded
                in Springfield, IL for adults. The word "koinonia" itself comes from the Greek
                word for "community". The Koinonia retreat is run by many parishes, dioceses,
                and college campuses in order to form communities and friendships based in
                Christ. DASK finds that the focus on community is helpful to people going
                through divorce and/or separation; we find that it is easy to feel "alone"
                going through this process.
            </p>
            <p>
                The theme of every DASK weekend is the Paschal Mystery; that is, the life,
                death, and resurrection of Jesus.
            </p>
            <h2>Where can I get more information?</h2>
            <li>Download our <a href="static/img/dask_brochure_2018.pdf">brochure</a>.</li>
            <li>Like our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/daskretreats">Facebook page</a>.</li>
            <li>Email us at <a href="mailto:daskretreatsk@gmail.com">daskretreats@gmail.com</a>.</li>
            <li>Follow us on Twitter <a href="https://www.twitter.com/daskretreats">@daskretreats</a>.</li>
            <h2>How do I sign up?</h2>
            <p>
                <a href="static/img/dask_brochure_2018.pdf">Download our brochure</a>, complete
                the registration form inside, and submit it via snail mail or
                <a href="mailto:daskretreats@gmail.com">email</a>. We host two retreat weekends
                a year: in the Spring at Columbia, IL, and in the Fall at Springfield, IL.
            </p>
        </section>
        </section>
        
        <section class="column right">
            <section>
                <h4>Donate</h4>
                <p>Coming soon</p>
            </section>
            <section style="margin-top: 15px">
                <article class="card">
                    <h4>Twitter</h4>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </article>
                <article class="card">
                    <h4>News</h4>
                    <p>Coming soon</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
    <p>
        Copyright (C) 2018: Divorced and Separated Koinonia, under the <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">CC BY-SA</a>.
        <br><a href="daskretreats@gmail.com.com">daskretreats@gmail.com</a>
    </p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

what you can do it you can use bootstrap for giving your website a grid structure

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class='container'><!--This will span the viewport size-->
<div class='row'>

<!--start First column oneThird size-->
<div class='col-sm-4'>
  content goes here......
</div>
<!--End First column oneThird size-->

<!--start second column oneThird size-->
<div class='col-sm-4'>
  content goes here......
</div>
<!--End second column oneThird size-->

<!--start third column oneThird size-->
<div class='col-sm-4'>
  content goes here......
</div>
<!--End third column oneThird size-->

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `<section class="column left">` wherein `css` you have define only `.left` and `.right`.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. But, both `.left` and `.right` are defined in main.css. `<section class="column right">` is used toward the bottom of index.html. Maybe you missed it?

Comment: No, I'm asking that you have created `css` with class name `.left` and `.right` then why are you using `column right` as a class name in your `index` file?

Comment: I mean to say, just remove `column` keyword from `<section class = "column right">`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following CSS elements of main.css. It should do the job.

```
 .row {
   display: flex;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

 .left .right {
    width: 25%;
    flex:1;
  }
.column {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #373737;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:15px;
   }

 /* Middle column */
 .middle {
    width: 50%;
    flex:1;
  }
```